# Industry standard on testing zoom levels

Tags: browsers

Is there an industry standard on how many zoom levels should be tested when working on a website?

Answer (score 5):

I know of no "Industry Standard".

And whenever I hear this sort of question, I always think "What *industry* do you mean?" The testing industry? The software industry? The website industry? The industry that offers an application identical to yours?

For *your* particular website, what kind of zooming do *your* users do? That's where you should be concentrating your testing.

I believe in response to a similar question you said "It depends on the requirements or what the stakeholders want." That was good advice. Unless you work in a regulated environment, check with your requirements and stakeholders.

Comment: At least he didn't ask what the 'best practice' was...

Comment: I might also ask why a user would need to zoom the browser.  If it happens a lot, that may tell you something about the usability of your site.  Most sites try to minimize the need for zooming, which may be why @katrinahispano has not seen a lot of feedback about zoom levels.

Comment: Isn't supporting zooming part of accessibility?  People with vision problems often need to zoom in order to be able to read text on web sites.  If your web site automatically re-adjust the size so as not to break the formatting (which I have actually seen quite a bit) then people with vision problems won't be able to view the site without use of third party tools (magnifying glass apps).  With that said, so long as the JavaScript isn't doing anything crazy to auto re-size then testing one zoom level should be equivalent to testing all.

Comment: Your right Sam. As my eyes get older I am very thankful of the ability to zoom :-). Another place we use zoom quite often is when presenting a site or projecting the desktop for a wider audience.